# Check Radio Button when clicking DIV

Tags: jquery, html

I'm writing a quiz application using php / jquery. The answer selections are contained like so:

```
<ul id="answers"> 
    <li> 
        <div> 
        <input type='radio' name='answer_id' value='313'> True
        </div> 
    </li> 
    <li> 
        <div> 
        <input type='radio' name='answer_id' value='314'> False
        </div> 
    </li> 
</ul>
```

After being styled w/ css, these answers appear in a container with one answer per line. Each answer has its own box inside the container. I want the user to be able to click anywhere inside the individual answer div and have the radio select become checked.

How can I activate the radio button check when a user clicks in the radio button's container div, using jquery?

Comment: related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/972366/jquery-focus-function-not-working-in-firefox/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Instead of using jQuery, this can all be done in native HTML using the [`<label>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp) element.  [Here is a sample](http://jsbin.com/iqesu/edit) of it in action.

```
<ul id="answers"> 
        <li> 
                <label> 
                    <input type='radio' name='answer_id' value='313'> True
                </label> 
        </li> 
        <li> 
                <label> 
                    <input type='radio' name='answer_id' value='314'> False
                </label> 
        </li> 
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Correct usage of the label tag is:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkme" name="checkme" /> <label for="checkme">Toggle this checkbox on/off</label>
```

for="..." always makes reference to the input's id.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with tj111, but if  does not always suit:

- More difficult to style.
- labels only work if there is text in them (thanks Michael)

Here is the alternative code using div and jQuery:

```
$('input:radio').click(ev){
    ev.stopPropagation();
}).parent().click(function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    $(this).children('input').click();
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

With the "active" class now you can even hide the radios and use stylesheet for highlighting.

Comment: That's... interesting. How about:         $('input:radio').click(function (ev) { ev.stopPropagation(); }).parent().click(function (ev) { ev.preventDefault(); $(this).children('input').click(); });

Comment: I found that labels only worked when there was text (or a significant amount of whitespace) available for clicking. Conversely, putting the click onto the parent would screw up the actual radio-click itself. Reworking romaninsh's code solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like:

```
$('#answers li div').click(function(){

  var r = $(this).find('input[type=radio]');
  if($(r).is(":checked"))
  {
    $(r).attr("checked", "");
  }
  else
  {
    $(r).attr("checked", "checked");
  }

});
```