# boostrap 3 modal , focus input field not working on firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I'm using modal from bootstrap 3 where it contains on input field

this modal is being launched using jquery code when page is loaded (not by clicking a button)

```
$().ready(function()
{
    $('#OTPModal').modal('show');
});
```

once the modal is shown I'm making the input become focus by this code

```
$('#OTPModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () 
{
    $('#OTPField').focus();
});
```

this code is working fine in google chrome, but it's not in firefox !

check the jsFiddle with chrome and firefox to see the different

https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/272015/

firefox version: 63.0.1 (64-bit)

chrome version: Version 70.0.3538.77 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Do you want the modal to open automatically when the page is opened or just when the button is pressed?

Comment: Actually, if you add these next lines: `var focused = document.activeElement; console.log(focused);` after `$('#OTPField').focus();`. Then you can see that the input is currently focused. It is very strange, I have tried a few things, but none had worked.

Comment: @Adi I want to make it automatically opened and automatically focused

Comment: @D.Smania I think firefox it self needs to do something in their browser to fix this issue. I don't believe there is anything from the javascript side to be done.

Comment: @sulaiman Have you tested this on a local environment (server), without Snippet or Fiddle framework? Just to be sure, because I have tested auto focus on an input element when document is ready on my local environment and it works (with Firefox), but this same don't work inside Fiddle or Snippet. I know is not the actual same problem (because yours use a modal) but you should give it a try if you not already do it.

Comment: This code works perfectly fine in Firefox if you just run it locally.

Comment: The problem exists within BS3, BS4 works just fine

Comment: If you see the fiddle directly http://fiddle.jshell.net/aq9Laaew/272015/show/ the example works just fine in firefox.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Focus fails on firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7046798/jquery-focus-fails-on-firefox)

Answer (score 0):

this problem is from fiddle site in firefox. see your code without fiddle iframe. 
https://fiddle.jshell.net/aq9Laaew/272015/show/

Comment: I have tried this in fiddle and its has the same issue.

Comment: check this link in firefox please. https://fiddle.jshell.net/h76wk0gp/show/

Comment: Yes it works, as does the original code when only displaying the result on /show , when editing in fiddle it does not work in yours and the original.