# focus not working for input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

MY focus is not working

Code on JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/JLULx/

HTML

```
<body>
    Email1<input type="email"><br/>

    <script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="selectors.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

Script ...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var email_default = "Enter your Email address";
    $('input [type="email"]').focus();
});
```

similar post :

1. [$.focus() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15859113/focus-not-working)

it says `$(document).ready` function should load completely and focus should be shift from *console* ..how to do it . I could't understand ...

2.[jQuery focus function not working in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972366/jquery-focus-function-not-working-in-firefox?rq=1)

This is doesnt seem to be relevant ..

Please  suggest

Comment: Can we see a demo? (jsfiddle/codepen/whatever)

Comment: ok......... i have edited initial post

Comment: move your js to the head before your ready function

Comment: code as as per tutorial ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if jQuery returned an object do this:

```
if($('.my-selector').length)) {
  // jQuery returned an object
}
```

You have an extra space in your selector. jQuery thinks your trying to access a child element of an `input` element. You need to change your code to this:

```
$('input[type="email"]').focus();
```

Also be sure that you are loading the jQuery library before you load your custom JavaScript.

http://jsfiddle.net/JLULx/2/

Comment: Cant this type of syntax error be catched on compile Time ?? Is there tool available for Jquery ?

Comment: I also thought the problem was the blank space, but it didn't work. The problem is with JSFiddle

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use an ID for the email field.

Example:

```
<input id="input-email" type="email"/>


$("#input-email").focus()
```

A more simple way is to use the HTML5 autofocus feature:

```
<input type="email" autofocus="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

Mmmmm, I think the problem is with JSFiddle.

For example if you run $("#run") on the browser console. It returns "null". It's supposed the ID "run" belongs to the run button on JSFiddle

Answer (score 0):

There are two things missing on you fiddle -
1. You haven't included proper jQuery library instead trying with pure JS.
2. in your selector remove the space between 'input' and '[type="email"]'. (as answered by RPM)